# iOS 11 prefersLargeTitles not updating until scroll

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I implemented a basic UIViewController with a UITableView that's wrapped in a UINavigationController. I set `prefersLargeTitles` to true:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationItem.title = "Coffees"
}
```

However, the title stays small until I scroll the view, at which point it enlarges. I tried moving that call to where I create the UINavigationController, but there was no effect. I am sure the navigationController is not nil when I set `prefersLargeTitles`.

Should I be updating that property elsewhere? Or should I file a Radar?

**Update:**

This only seems to happen if my view contains a `UITableView` or is itself a `UITableViewController`

Comment: Mucking with the `navigationBar` should generally be done in `viewWillAppear(_:)`, not `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: same issue here

Comment: I tried moving it to `viewWillAppear`. Same issue.

Comment: @JohnBreen I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: having the same issue as well, appears to be an iOS bug and I haven't found a fix yet

Comment: Bug, the nav item large title automatic setting is not appreciated, even in Xcode 9 GM. See assb10yr's workaround below.

Comment: having this same exact issue

Comment: edgesForExtendedLayout = []

Comment: Check this topic - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46703469/shrink-large-title-when-scrolling-not-uitableviewcontroller-ios-11

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had the same problem. Although you are not using Storyboards but I hope this could help someone. I checked "Prefer Large Titles" for the Navigation Controller (not the View Controller) I embedded my TableViewController in. All the View Controllers after the Navigation Controller turned and had large titles, and it should work.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: my issue was different - to hide large title in first VC and show Large title in secondVC , in Second VC large title truncate for very first time , by disabling it form storyboard works for me

Comment: I haven't written iOS code in over a year, but I gave up on programmatic views for the most part and went back to storyboards despite my frustrations.

Comment: God bless you !

Answer (score 56):

For me the only working solution is:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.sizeToFit()
}
```

in

```
viewWillAppear()
```

Comment: I hate that this fixed my problem. +1

Comment: Fixed my problem too.

Comment: Fixed my problem too

Comment: Worked for me to, XCode 12 and iOS 14. Sending it to main queue was not neccesary though as viewWillAppear() is already called from main queue

Comment: Yup, can confirm calling sizeToFit() without DispatchQueue works fine as long as it is in viewWillAppear() instead of viewDidLoad()

Comment: it worked with me in viewDidLoad without dispatchQueue

Comment: can you explain why this works?

Comment: Damn this fixed my problem too that the searhcbar embedded in the navigationbar was somehow scrolled invisible. Searhcbar only became visible when I dragged the table down...

Answer (score 55):

I recently hit the same issue and none of the suggestions worked for me. Instead, all I needed to do was to invoke `sizeToFit()`. Sample code:

```
private func configureNavigator() {
    guard let navigationController = navigationController else { return }
    navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
    navigationController.navigationBar.sizeToFit()
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This worked for me as well, when ViewController was inside a UITabBarController.

Comment: This was perfect `navigationController?.navigationBar.sizeToFit()`

Comment: Perfect. I spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem and this worked. Thank you

Comment: Worked perfectly. Really simple UITableViewController. Large title did not work only if I had a tableFooterView. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me as well using a search controller with large title. I had to call from viewWillAppear and set navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false and later call navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true in viewDidAppear.

Comment: the problem is when setting a tableFooterView and this solution fixes it. thanks

Comment: This did work but showing some glitches while changing small navigation bar to large navigation bar when coming back from other viewcontroller who have small navbar. It shows no animation in transition.
Could someone please suggest something on this.

Answer (score 48):

I had the same issue only on one tableview ...

I had to set :

```
self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

so that my tableview stop scrolling when uiviewcontroller was loaded.

It's the tableview automatic scrolling that makes the large title being hidden

Hope this helps

Comment: This covers up the first row behind the nav bar with large title?

Comment: edgesForExtendedLayout = []

Comment: Bro, your solution helped me. Thank you!

Comment: This did not work for me and in fact caused my content to move under the navigation bar (it's a translucent nav bar)

Comment: After trying everything suggested this is the one that worked for me (using a UIViewController with UITableView inside)

Answer (score 7):

Same issue with Swift 5.2

my view contains tableView and prefersLargeTitles is not updating until scroll, I fixed it by setting

[image]

```
self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Answer (score 6):

Modifying the contentInset of the tableView with `top:1` will force the NavigationBar to expand and display the large titles.

Obj-C

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Swift

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 0, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

*Note:* If you have a `tableView.reloadData()` in your `viewWillAppear` make sure to call it after editing the `contentInset`

Comment: This by it self it does anything, I think you should add the configurations you've set in the tableView and navigation bar

Answer (score 4):

In my case the solution was to set tableView's top align to Safe Area and not Superview

Comment: This is correct - but it wrecks the table view on iOS versions prior to 11

Comment: Arnaud, good answer. And best profile picture on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue and found that it’s usually best to set the `prefersLargeTitles` property from the view controller or object that sets it up, and to do so before it is presented.

For instance, if the view controller in question is shown upon app launch:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let someViewController: UIViewController = CustomViewController()

    let theNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: someViewController)
    theNavController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

    window.rootViewController = theNavController
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

or if presenting a particular view controller:

```
let someViewController: UIViewController = CustomViewController()

let theNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: someViewController)
theNavController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

present(theNavController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I found this method to be a more sure-fire way to ensure that the navigation title is displayed accordingly. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: To add to your second example: I discovered that if you create another view controller and immediately push it on the navigation controller, if you go back via tap on the back button to the first view controller there is a glitch which makes the title text disappear. You have to call `layoutIfNeeded()` on the first ViewController to get this fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I have wasted some considerable amount of time on this as `prefersLargeTitle` saga works on some view controllers as expected and with some it produces the same issue above.

Solution for me was to uncheck Extended Edges Under Top Bars in IB - for those view controllers who show large title momentarily until the contents of the table view are loaded then navigation bar jumps back up to regular size. It only shows the large title when scrolling the table view down.

This is backward compatible with iOS 10 and does not leave any empty space above the first row in the table view.

I had checked `prefersLargeTitle` on the navigation controllers attributes inspector only in IB - nothing in code. Same for `largeTitleDisplayMode = .always`

As for why this happens with some view controllers and not others, I have absolutely no idea!

Answer (score 2):

In the storyboard I set the Navigation Item's `Large Title` to `Never`.

[image: Navigation Item]

In my ViewController's viewDidLoad method I set the following:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

Comment: I'm not using storyboards

Comment: This work around is needed even in the Xcode 9 GM. Seems like the nav bar's large title font is ignored too.

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically:

1. In AppDelegate.swift:

```swift
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: ViewController())
        window?.rootViewController = navigationController
```

2. In ViewController:

```swift
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
    }

   override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        view.addSubview(tableView)
        view.addSubview(loadingView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor),
            tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.heightAnchor)
            ])
    }
```

Make sure your `tableView` has beed previously added to your view.

Comment: This, this has solved my 2 month problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of the other answers but what worked for me was to set the content offset of my `UITableView` to `CGPoint(x: 0, y: -1)` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -1), animated: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue and, in my case, it turns out that the Storyboard structure that was working in iOS 10 with Swift 3 (and also works with iOS 11 with Swift 3) was causing the issue on iOS 11 with Swift 4.

To elaborate:

I had a regular UIViewController in my storyboard that I had set to a UINavigationController subclass (my hierarchy is similar to yours, with UITabBarController subclass → UINavigationController subclass → UITableViewController subclass).

In iOS 10, this worked fine.

In iOS 11, this also works fine when you run the existing Swift 3 app.

However, with the Swift 4 app, running on iOS 11, I was seeing the same symptoms you described (large titles only appear when you pull/scroll the view down).

To fix, I replaced the UIViewController-based elements in the Storyboard with actual UINavigationController instances (which contain a UINavigationBar explicitly in the Storyboard – I have a hunch this is where the crux of the issue stems from, as the UIViewController instances didn’t have that element explicitly declared within the Storyboard).

Anyway, that fixed the issue for me.

I’ll file radar as this looks like a Swift 4-based regression as, for me, it works both in iOS 10 with Swift 3 and in iOS 11 with Swift 3.

Comment: I am not using storyboards, so I don't think this is what's going on with my app

Answer (score 1):

General changing the behaviour of the `navigationBar` should be done in `viewWillAppear(_:)`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

After doing that it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

One more possible solution is to end refresh in your refreshHandler(). like this-

```
@objc func refreshPage() {
    self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing() //End here
    self.loadTableData() //Get fresh data and reload table
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue via storyboard

1. Navigation Controller -> Navigation Bar -> Attributes inspector -> Prefers Large Titles(Checked)
2. View Controller -> Navigation Item -> Attributes inspector -> Large Title (Automatic or Always checked)

Answer (score 1):

I think It does seem a little bit dummy but I effectively solved the problem with this:

```
self.navigationItem.prompt = ""

self.navigationItem.prompt = nil
```

It's like navigationBar needs a sort of update in one of its elements to update the layout.

Sometimes to update something in navigationBar I need to hide and unhide it.. That's why I think there is a best way to do it.. For the moment that's my workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with navigation bar, but in my case it had a custom title view, and navigation bar remained empty until table view is scrolled down, which triggered `UILayoutContainerView` to layout its subviews, one of which are navigation controller's view and navigation bar. I assume the root of it is the same as the large title navigation bar issue.

Anchoring `tableView` to the `safeAreaLayoutGuide` didn't work out for me, `largeTitleDisplayMode` couldn't be other then `.never`

So I managed to fix it by calling `self.navigationController?.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints` in the top presented controller's `viewDidAppear(animated:)` function, or scheduling this call for the next run loop in `viewWillAppear(animated:)`, like:

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.navigationController?.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
}
```

In this case, navigation bar appeared with the correct content and size along with presenting transition, instead of popping in after transition was completed

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is setting the `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true` before calling tableviews reload method.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above for tableview also works for collection view if parent view not scrolled before navigation:

```
self.collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

If parent view scrolled before navigation the solution above did not work in my case. I had to add the answer above as:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.sizeToFit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That does seem like a weird behavior at first, but try setting the `navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode` to `always`. The default is `automatic` - and it's not defined how that works in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/2909056-largetitledisplaymode).

Also wrote / will update an answer about large titles [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44448038/826435).

Comment: I tried that as well. It didn't work for me either :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. The view is a table view. The property of `prefersLargeTitles` is set at `viewDidLoad` event. Then I set view's title in `viewWillAppear` event.

```
override open func viewDidLoad() {
   if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    ...
}

override open func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationItem.title = "something"
    ...
}
```

In my prepare segue event, I set navigation item's tile to `nil` so that the next view left navigation var item displays "Back" automatically.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
                      sender: Any?) {
    self.navigationItem.title = nil
    ...
}
```

The first time the table view displays large title correctly. However, if I select a row to next view and back to the table view, the navigation item's title becomes empty.

After several hours' struggling, I finally find out that the view's title should be set in `viewDidAppear` event! It seems that whatever set to view's title in `Will` event would be reset by UIKit internally back to nil. So it has to be set in a different event.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   self.navigationItem.title = "something"
   ...
}

override open func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // self.navigationItem.title = "something" // Remove it and set title in Did event!
    ...
}
```

Before I introduced this iOS 11 new feature, my app runs OK. It seems that the new feature has some changes in UIKit so that the previous version app may need some updates/changes to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by changing order of views in my ViewController in InterfaceBuilder.

It seems like if the first view in Hierarchy is NOT a ScrollView then NavigationBar appears in LargeTitle mode and does not animates together with scroll view. If you need to have Navigation Bar title to reflect your scroll then   you need to put your scroll view as the first in view hierarchy.

Also, I am not completely sure in this but looks like Navigation Bar appearance in standard or Large Title mode depends on views hierarch of previous Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue for me with a `UITableViewController` added to a `UIViewController`. In my instance, these view controllers are themselves embedded in a `UITabBarController` and only the first tab displayed correctly used a large title. Other tabs required a manual scroll before the large title was displayed.

The only thing I could get to work was adjusting the `contentInset` as per @pau-senabre's answer, except I the `top` inset wasn't helpful for me. Instead, I set the `left` inset and then reset it on the next runloop.

```
private var isFirstAppearance = true

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if isFirstAppearance {
        applyLargeTitlesFix()
    }
}

private func applyLargeTitlesFix() {
    let originalInset = tableViewController.tableView.contentInset
    tableViewController.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 1, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.tableViewController.tableView.contentInset = originalInset
    }
    isFirstAppearance = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here with Swift 4.2, iOS 12, and refactored Storyboards.

Tried adding `prefersLargeTitles = true` to `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad`, but neither fixed my issue.

Instead, I copied the refactored storyboards back into main.storyboard and found the option to enable large titles in IB. Set that option, then refactored the storyboards back out and everything is working now.  For some reason, the initial refactoring stripped out the option and I couldn't enable it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (iOS 14, Xcode 12.2).

It only affected navigation controllers displaying table views.

I had originally set `tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()` to get rid of extra separators after the last cell. **Setting the footer view to `nil` fixed the scrolled-up navigation title.**

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue.

I have set below code in viewdidload method. and it get fixed.

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never