# ios navigation bar large title issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, ios11

I'm using Swift 4. I wish to show the navigation bar large title. When I scroll I expect the navigation bar to expand/collapse.

I'm showing same content on both collection view and table view. Like showing data on tile view and list view. When the user toggles the view, either collection view or table view will show.

I have referred the link [Shrink large title when scrolling (not UITableViewController) iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46703469/shrink-large-title-when-scrolling-not-uitableviewcontroller-ios-11/46713647).

As suggested in the above link, I have added the collection view next to the safe area. So the navigation bar with large title gets scrolled. No problem with the collection view.

I have added the table view next to the collection view. Here the large title doesn't scroll up. If I interchange the collection view and table view on storyboard, the large title works fine on table view.

But I have to show both the controls on my view and the large titles should work on both the controls.

Kindly help me to solve this issues. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone please help me out on this?